# How to use certificate with restClient C#

Tags: c#, ssl, asp.net-web-api, rest-client, pfx

I have a .pfx file and also i generated .ct and .key based on .pfx file...

I am able make a request using Postman, but I am unable to send a request from C# code.
Here is the code:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://example.org/api/Schema/findColumn?columnName=Form_Id&TableName=Form");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Referer", "https://.org");
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");
        request.AddHeader("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
        request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
        request.AddHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
        request.AddHeader("Host", "abc.org");



        X509Certificate2 certificates = new X509Certificate2(@"F:\Certificate\cert-test.pfx", "123456");
        var t = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();



        client.ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection() { certificates };

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Its says "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."

Comment: Is this a self-signed certificate?

Comment: Can you enable tracing against System.Net to get add'l details?

Comment: yeah its self signed @Jasen

Comment: You may need to sign the certificate with your own CA certificate. You can create a CA and install it in the cert store then use it to sign the test certificate.